# Diaspora two handed melee weapon

Tags: fate, diaspora

In Diaspora the two handed stunt for melee says "Weapon is designed for two-handed use and is awkward in the hands of those not sufficiently strong. The wielder may amplify his Skill check with his Stamina. 1bp."
What do they mean by *amplify*? One of the more experienced players said that I only add one point to my roll, but I don't understand why if that is the case it doesn't just say "add one to your skill check" instead .

Answer (score 8):

A higher skill may augment another one in Diaspora by +1 when they work together. In other words, you get the +1 only if your Stamina is or higher than your Weapons skill.

> *Diaspora p. 10*
>
> #### skill a is amplified by skill b
>
> This indicates that Skill A is used for the check. If Skill B exceeds Skill A, then an additional +1 is granted. For example, a Brawling check amplified by Strength (as might happen if a character tries to throw a large table during a fight) with Brawling 2 and Strength
> 5 would be checked at 3 (Brawling rank +1) + 4dF.